# Disable selected value from DataBase

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, mariadb

I'm building an appointment system to a barbershop.
It works like this:

1. Appointment page in PHP where the client will add their name, phone number, what they want, the date and time (like 2PM).
2. This will add to the database these informations
3. The admin page will fetch this data from the db and display to the barber the appoiments

My problem: Lets say that the barber has 8AM and 9PM work hours. A client wants 8AM appointment, and the next one that will make the appointment should not see that the 8AM "space" is available, only 9AM and posterior hours.

How can I do that? I thought that I would make an code that reads all data from the db to that day and fetch all taken hours.

Reservation form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Agendar
    </title>
    <link href="theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
    // (A) PROCESS RESERVATION
    if (isset($_POST['date'])) {
      require "reserve.php";
      if ($_RSV->save(
        $_POST['date'], $_POST['slot'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['email'],
        $_POST['tel'], $_POST['notes'])) {
        echo "<div class='ok'>Reserva feita! Entraremos em contato caso haja necessidade.</div>";
      } else { echo "<div class='err'>".$_RSV->error."</div>"; }
    }
    ?>

    <!-- (B) RESERVATION FORM -->
    <h1>Agendar um horário</h1>
    <form id="resForm" method="post" target="_self">
      <label for="res_name">Nome</label>
      <input type="text" required name="name" placeholder="Seu nome"/>
      <label for="res_tel">Telefone</label>
      <input type="text" required name="tel" placeholder="(12) 12345-6789"/>
      <label for="res_notes">Barba, cabelo ou os dois?</label>
      <select required name="notes">
        <option disabled selected value> -- Selecione -- </option>
        <option value="Barba">Barba</option>
        <option value="Cabelo">Cabelo</option>
        <option value="Cabelo e Barba">Cabelo e Barba</option>
      </select>
      <label>Date</label>
      <input type="date" required id="res_date" name="date" placeholder="<?=date("Y-m-d")?>">
      <label>Horário</label>
      <select required name="slot">
        <option disabled selected value> -- Selecione -- </option>
        <option value="8:00">8:00</option>
        <option value="9:00">9:00</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" value="Reservar"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Admin page:

```
<?php
include_once 'database.php';
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM reservations");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <title> Agendamentos</title>
 </head>
<body>
<?php
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
?>
  <table>
  
  <tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Horário</td>
    <td>Nome</td>
    <td>Telefone</td>
    <td>Vai fazer</td>
  </tr>
<?php
$i=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row["res_id"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["res_date"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["res_slot"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["res_name"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["res_tel"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["res_notes"]; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
$i++;
}
?>
</table>
 <?php
}
else{
    echo "No result found";
}
?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `reservations` (
 `res_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `res_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `res_slot` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
 `res_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `res_tel` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
 `res_notes` text DEFAULT NULL,
 `res_email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`res_id`),
 KEY `res_date` (`res_date`),
 KEY `res_slot` (`res_slot`),
 KEY `res_name` (`res_name`),
 KEY `res_tel` (`res_tel`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin
```

Comment: Are all appointments for 1 hour?

Comment: I'm doing for 1 hour but I guess that the barber makes 30 minutes appointments

Comment: Simplest solution: add `is_busy` column to the appointment table. Better, add many-to-many relation table to connect client with appointment.

Comment: Could you share a example code, please? I'm new to php and db

Comment: show us your structure of `reservations` and `clients` tables

Comment: I only got the reservations table, as you can see in the image in the question

Comment: That's OK for me, however next time when someone will ask you for *structure*, just run this SQL query in your PhpMyAdmin: `show create table reservations` than in response options choose `Full texts` and copy the code

Comment: Just edited the post as you told @biesior

Comment: Rule number one: **ALWAYS** use `utf-8` encoding for your DBs, tables and columns, otherwise some day you'll find, that you can't handle client i.e. with umlaut characters in his name.

Answer (score 1):

First your `reservations` table should not contain users' data like `name`, `tel`, `email` instead you just create `clients` table and store each client as a single row. Next In your `reservations` table add column `client_id` of integer type, where you'll keep numeric id of client in the `clients` table. This way you do not repeat client's data. You can fetch data from many tables in one query with `JOIN` statement. That's one-to-one relation (one reservation can have only one client).

Rest is rather easy, when you generating list of available

1. Select all rows for given day, which has assigned client `select * from reservations where client_id > 0`
2. In PHP generate appointments only for these hours, which has NOT row in DB

Tip: as a programmer it will be easier to store hours in DB in 24h format, that way you'll use `8:00` or `16:00` instead of `8`+`AM` vs `8`+`PM`. Of course at the end you can display `8:00 PM` on the page.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `reservations` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `res_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `slot` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

INSERT INTO reservations (res_date, slot, client_id) VALUES ('2021-02-25', '08:00:00', 1);
INSERT INTO reservations (res_date, slot, client_id) VALUES ('2021-02-26', '11:30:00', 2);
INSERT INTO reservations (res_date, slot, client_id) VALUES ('2021-02-27', '16:30:00', 3);

CREATE TABLE `clients` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

INSERT INTO clients (first_name, last_name, email, phone) VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@doe.tld', '+1234');
INSERT INTO clients (first_name, last_name, email, phone) VALUES ('Jane', 'Doe', 'jane@doe.tld', '+4321(7)');
INSERT INTO clients (first_name, last_name, email, phone) VALUES ('Johan', 'Müller', 'mueller@foode', '+49123');
```

`JOIN` - querying connected tables at once:

```sql
SELECT reservations.*, clients.*
FROM reservations
LEFT JOIN clients ON (reservations.client_id = clients.id)
```

Comment: Great! I'll use the reservations table just to show the data to the barber, in case he needs to call the client or view the reservations in the HTML page.
I'll create another table just like you told!

Comment: Depends what you need - you can just do `JOIN` query to fetch data from multiple tables and/or create separate queries for each.

Comment: This edit you've made resolves the "two appointments in the same time" issue @biesior?

Comment: If you'll program it - iw will. Here's just a sample of JOIN query, it's up to you how you'll use it.

Answer (score 1):

you have to check the available hours.

- before generating select box on reservation page, you may execute a select query  to check if barber is available or not!I recommend you to use 24hour format for this part.

1- a functin to create times between 8:00 to 21:00

```php
    function dailyTime(){
        $time = [];
        $start = 8;
        $end = 21;
        for ($time = $start; $time <= $end; $time++) {
         array_push($time,date("H:00", mktime($time+1)));
        }
        return $time;
    }
```

2- do the filteration for options:

a) generate time between 8 - 21
b) unset reserved time from array
c) make select box for the rest of items left in time array

```php
          <select required name="slot">
            <option disabled selected value> -- Selecione -- </option>
            <?php
            $availableTimes = dailyTime();
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM reservations");
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                if (($key = array_search($row['res_slot'], $availableTimes)) !== false) {
                    unset($availableTimes[$key]);
                }
            }
            foreach($availableTimes as $free){
                    echo '<option>'.$free.'<option>';
            }
            
            ?>
          </select>
```

Comment: I tried your code @milad-elyasi but it didn't generated the hours